# Any set of polynomials such that there is exactly one polynomial of each degree is also a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Any set of polynomials such that there is exactly one polynomial of each degree is also a basis of vector space of polynomials.How to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. Can you show that $c$ (with $c \neq 0$) and $aX+b$ (with $a \neq 0$) form a basis of the space of polynomials of degree $\leqslant 1$? Then try to extend the argument to larger degrees.

Comment: yeah sure .. Then should extend it by what? induction?

Comment: @raghu Yes, by induction.

Comment: then i should assume that {p1(x),p2..............pn(x)} form a basis  of polynomials of atmost degree n .. right?? and then show that {p1(x),p2..............pn(x),pn+1(x)} form basis of at most n+1 degree polynomials?? right

Comment: @raghu Exactly.

Comment: but how do u show the linear independence part?

Comment: Did you solve the case $n=1$? Then practice again with the case $n = 2$.

Comment: yeah i get the piling coefficnts and making it zero thing . But can u say the linear independance of n+1 from that of up to pnx

Comment: What is the dimension of the space of polynomials of degree $\leqslant n$?

Comment: thats n. but the inductive argument should be used to prove that {p1(x),p2..............pn(x),pn+1(x)} form a basis right?

Comment: That is not $n$, but $n + 1$. Now, if you have a set of $n+1$ linearly independent vectors, you know they form a base.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You can prove that they are independent in a straight forward fashion using the fundamental theorem of algebra. Write down a linear combination equal to zero.  All the coefficients are then zero.  You'll easily get that you have the trivial linear combination.

But then $n$ independent vectors form a basis.